# Access webpage resources from WebBrowser

Tags: webbrowser-control

Is there a way or a workaround to access resources loaded by a page in a WebBrowser, either the Windows Forms WebBrowser or the Windows Phone WebBrowser (and/or WPF WebBrowser)?

I've always used the DocumentText property of WebBrowser for web crawling and automated tasks, but never knew if resources are actually accessible from code, just like when we use firebug or the Chrome console to retrieve some documents that have been fetched when loading a page.

Comment: You can access any element in the `DOM` and obtain any attribute from them. So pretty much, you can easily obtain the `src` attribute of an image element, or the `href` attribute of a `a` tag, or the `src` of css and javascripts, and then by either using `sockets` or depending your programming language the `WebClient` classes obtain the resources themselves.

Comment: I noticed that with the WP8 WebBrowser (a mini IE10), all I can do is convert it to string to get the HTML. I'm currently using a WebClient in parallel as a workaround. However, what I understood by reading WP8 documentation is that some network functionalities have been deliberately limited in .Net. There's a C++ WebSocket API using things like socket2.h, but I feel that there's probably no pure sniffing capabilities to intercept TCP communications.